# Java Control Panel and Java desktop apps non-interactive

Tags: java, troubleshooting

If I execute

```
/usr/java/default/bin/javaws target.jnlp
```

I get the window for the Java application, but it's non-interactive. I can move the window around on the desktop, but I can't interact with any of the buttons or clickables inside the window. I do [DDG](https://duckduckgo.com) searches for debugging ideas and learn how to launch the Control Panel.

```
/usr/java/default/bin/ControlPanel
```

That *also* launches without any ability to interact with it. All I can do is minimize or maximize the window. I can't close it, and I can't do anything inside it. The min/max suggests this is not an X11/GNOME problem. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Which version of Java are you running? What X11 window manager are you using? Are you using any unusual X11 server (i.e. not traditional Xorg)?

Comment: Could be a Group Policy setting, http://woshub.com/java-settings-management-with-group-policies/ , or it might be that you must run the CPL as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I had previously experimented with the resolution for [RHEL-07-020020](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_7/2020-01-02/finding/V-71971). It turns out that attempting to resolve that particular STIG breaks a whole bunch of other things. I haven't yet looked at whether anyone has posted the research on the complete SELinux rule changes that would be required to accommodate RHEL-07-020020.